# Oauth2 Golang - Own database and users

Tags: authentication, go, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm building a web application in Golang, and at the moment I'm struggling with the authentication/authorization mechanisms.

I want to deploy this app to different platforms (browsers, androids, etc). To achieve this I chosed to use oauth 2.0, namely this lib: https://github.com/golang/oauth2 .

The problem I'm facing is how to achieve this with my own database and users. The lib has a jwt package (https://github.com/golang/oauth2/tree/master/jwt) and also has a package clientcredentials (https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/clientcredentials/clientcredentials.go) that can be used for 2-legged Oauth 2.0, but I have no idea how to achieve this, and can't find any example showing it. Which package should I use? The token should be set when user sends a POST with its credentials at http://example.domain/login.

Can someone provide me some hints / show me a simple example?

Comment: From a simple web search, there seems to be a variety of Go OAuth2 server libraries to choose from. Read through a few of their READMEs, pick one that looks like it will work for you, and just try using it. Post a concrete question if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored solutions such as [ory/hydra](https://github.com/ory/hydra), which will handle everything OAuth2/OpenID related and let you handle user authentication?

Implementing your own OAuth2 provider is dangerous territory. It only takes one misread RFC and BOOM! Security vulnerability. It's typically better to entrust that responsibility to established security experts or lasting projects as opposed to home-grown remedies.

Of course, this isn't to say that everybody needs to jump onto the hype train and use this cool new software. In fact, I would urge the opposite: if you are a competent security analyst and feel comfortable writing an OAuth2/OpenID Connect implementation, go right ahead! But us normal people who don't want our hair to gray before we are thirty will use existing technologies to our advantage.

[image: So Trump must have been busy working with webRTC.]

Comment: The idea was not to implement an OAuth2 provider at all. The idea was to use the jwt package from that lib to achieve authentication and authorization with my own database and users. Since I didn't find any example with this package, I ended up using this lib: https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go .